# How to change array value from string to integer

Tags: php, arrays, string, types

I have the following array and I would like to change each [Entry] value from a string to an integer:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [Time] => 06:08:00 [Entry] => 250 ) [1] => Array ( [Time] => 08:08:00 [Entry] => 230 )

I am trying in this manner, which seems to change the type within the loop but the change does not seem to take effect outside the loop. I'm new at this, so I'm probably overlooking something, and most likely a simpler way to accomplish this.

```
foreach($data as $inner) {
foreach($inner as $key=>$val) {
    if($key == 'Entry') {
        $newval = intval($val);
        $val = $newval;
        echo(gettype($val));//integer
        }
    }
}

echo(gettype($data[0]['Entry'])); //string
```

Comment: You're not changing the array's fields. Try this `$inner[$key] = intval($val)`

Comment: The $key referenced is an instance of the value, not the refernce in the array itself. Try... `$data[$key] = (int)$value`.

Comment: *WHY* are you want to do this? In general you don't need to care about "types" in php. (except some special cases).

Comment: I want to json_encode the array and pass it on in an Ajax call where I need the value to be an integer. I thought it would be easier to do this on the server side.

Comment: @user2232681 But javascript doesn't really care about types for the most part either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not changing the Value of the element in the array.

```
foreach($data as &$inner) {        
        $inner['Entry'] = intval($inner['Entry']);        
}
```

To modify the array elements within the loop, you have to precede `$inner` with &. i.e. The value will be assigned by reference.

For details see [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-cast it to the actual array.

```
foreach($data as $dkey => $inner) {
    foreach($inner as $ikey => $val) {
        if ($ikey == 'Entry') {
             $data[$dkey][$ikey] = intval($val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed an `i` in `ikey` on line 3